# Where to find a soccer only SFX library

Tags: sfx

I cant seem to find a soccer only SFX library anywhere. They are always sports themed with maybe 10 soccer SFX total. while the other 200 are everything from billiards to ping pong. World cup advertising is coming up and im hoping to find a soccer sfx library. Kicks, nets, dribbles, passes, traps, slides, throw-ins, fouls, whistles, crowds.

Help?

Noah

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest, if you have the means, approaching your local football club to ask permission to record during their training or at a match.

Especially if your not finding what you want in a sports library this way you will get exactly what your after.

All the Best